# Is there a way to repeat a specific statement to avoid overly long IFS in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently trying to make a small excel sheet which automatically plans out a measurement plan.

However, I need a specific value to remain below a certain threshold of 1100 and when it surpasses that, subtract 930.

So far, I haven't found a short way to do that as I need a very long IFS-statement at the moment.

My question is; is there a way to let the statement repeat itself until the initial condition has been met?

An example of my current line is:

```
=MROUND(IFS(J3="", "",
  Q28>7510, Q28-8*930, 
  Q28>6580, Q28-7*930, 
  Q28>5650, Q28-6*930, 
  Q28>4720, Q28-5*930, 
  Q28>3790, Q28-4*930, 
  Q28>2960, Q28-3*930, 
  Q28>2030, Q28-2*930, 
  Q28>1100, Q28-930, 
  Q28<1100, Q28), 10)
```

Where it first starts by rounding the eventual answer to the nearest 10, after that it starts the IFS-query in which it checks whether the cell next to it is empty to not make the list too long.

After that I have a repeating statement that constantly checks whether the value is above 1100 and subtracts integer amounts of 930.

I have just started with Excel, so I might've overlooked a much simpler answer!

Comment: I'm getting #NUM! after 16 iterations for some reason, the first 15 work perfectly though!

Comment: Changed it to 
=IF(J2="","",(MROUND(D45-MMULT(--(D45>{0,1100,2030,2960,3790,4720,5650,6580,7510}),{0;930;930;930;930;930;930;930;930}),10)))
And it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's the change is a constant of 930 we could use this:
`=IF(J3="","",MROUND(IF(Q28<=1100,Q28,Q28-(1+INT((Q28-1100)/930))*930),10))`

Answer (score 1):

The approach would be using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd> function to create the threshold:

```
=IF(J3="","",(MROUND(Q28-
    MMULT(--(Q28>{0,1100,2030,2960,3790,4720,5650,6580,7510}),
    {0;930;930;930;930;930;930;930;930}),10)))
```